# List modificaiton Dynamically : more elements supplied than there are to replace

Tags: r

I am trying to manipulate list dynamically. There are two list

```
List structure:#List 1: file.cuisine.table

  $ :List of 3
   ..$ id         : num 8753
   ..$ cuisine    : chr "italian"
   ..$ ingredients: chr [1:6] "olive oil" "olives" "salt" "blood orange" ...
[list output truncated]

$ :List of 3 #List 2: unique.ing.list # ingredient list
  ..$                   : chr "ground turkey"
  ..$ is.present.cuisine: chr [1:3] "chinese" "mexican" "italian"
  ..$ is.present.recipe : num [1:5] 45887 41995 49136 10276 8820
  [list output truncated]
```

I am trying to reverse map ingredients to cuisine. The lines code

```
cuisine.new <- "mexican" #(new recipe discovered while traversing the table file.cuisine.table )
temp.cuisine <- unique.ing.list[[1]][["is.present.cuisine"]]
temp.recepie <- unique.ing.list[[1]][["is.present.recipe"]]
temp.cuisine[length(temp.cuisine)+1] <- cuisine.new
unique.ing.list[[pos]][["is.present.cuisine"]] <- temp.cuisine

 error: Error in unique.ing.list[[pos]][["is.present.cuisine"]] <- temp.cuisine :   more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

These lines code break inbetween while traversing "file.cuisine.table". Hence i am not sure how to debug. Any clues.

Comment: `unique.ing.list[[pos]][["is.present.cuisine"]]` seems to contain 3 elements and you are trying to replace it with 4 elements, (3 `temp.cuisine` + 1 `cuisine.new`)